# Modal Window won't close after loading a new page in it

Tags: javascript

Having weird problem in Drupal 6.  We are loading a modal window that searches for places.  The results are displayed, then someone clicks on one of the results, the parent window places that info into a field there.  Then the modal window closes.

I'm using:

`Drupal.modalFrameChild.triggerParentEvent('childClose', false); return false;`

to close it.

To refer to the parent window fields, I use

`parent.parent.getElementById('<field>').value = "";`

This is working fine.

There is a link at the bottom that allows you to add your own business if you cant find one in results.  This loads a NEW page within the modal window.  Once everything is added and submitted, I run the same javascript code.  All the parent.parent pieces work, but the close window one doesn't.

I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'eventHandlerName' of undefined`

Anyone had this issue?  Does loading a new page into the modal window cause it to lose the parent/child connection?  I'm at a loss...

Comment: I'm working with Dave on this project - just adding a follow up for clarification. We have a node/add form page and one of the fields opens a modal window, where you can do a search & select an item, and there's some custom javascript that fires to insert your selection back onto the node/add form & then it closes the modal window, using the code Dave indicated above. There's also an option to add a new item manually if you don't find it by searching.  If you click the "add" link, it loads a separate node/add form for a different content type in the modal window.

Comment: cont'd - And that data populates back to the original node/add form, no problem.  But the modal window won't close. So... yeah; we're trying to noodge that one out.